# Flutter iOS app needs passcode for Google Sign In

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, google-signin

Using flutter code when I tries to login via Google Sign in on my iOS device, I get following error:

> Your administrator requires you to set a passcode on this device to access this account. Please set a passcode and try again.

While on other apps it does not mandate to have passcode on iphone for logging using google

[image]

Comment: For the google sign-in button which behavior type are you using? Native? Web?

Comment: My app is in flutter and I am using https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in package

Comment: Did you get any solution???

Comment: @MunishThakur??

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to change the password settings of your domain: [Device Policy Alert requires I set a passcode for access account - how do I disable?](https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/8252501?hl=en)

> You must be the administrator of your domain to do this, as far as I
>   know.
>
> Login at admin.google.com and navigate to:
>
> Device management >> Password Settings
>
> Then uncheck the box labeled "Require users to set a password."

Comment: Yes, but i want any use to login in the app. Aap should bypass this itself.

Comment: This option is not to enable or disable the login, is to specify a password before you can login.

Comment: Yes, the problem statement is that: "on other apps on my phone, google signing via email works fine, while on my app with same email it ask for passcode"

Comment: This is strange for me as behaviour should be same for all the apps.Other apps must be doing something by which their app gets successful login event while my stuck in passcode pop-up

Comment: Because this setting depends on the domain of the app. The other apps domain must have that option "Require users to set a password." disabled and your app domain doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, please let me know how to configure domain for the app

Comment: It's in the answer. You need to change that settings from admin.google.com > Device management > Password Settings > Require users to set a password

Comment: I am not the admin for corporate user and it might come to other users. My problem is that my App should be able to login if their admin checked "Require users to set a password".

Comment: I am using same email says "abc@xyz.com" and on my app it does show "passcode" popup while for the other apps like Google photos etc it does not show any popup. I am using same email id and same phone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201817/discussion-between-pablo-barrera-and-munish-thakur).

Comment: Changing Passwork permission worked only for particular domain but not for others like.. I created Firebase config by company account "abc@xyz" and disable password requirement from admin. That works fine. But for other corporate account say "aaa@zzz.com" same issue of passcode appears

Comment: and with that aaa@zzz.com the issue of passcode happens on any app or just in your app?

Comment: Just my app only (Which is build in flutter), Other apps taking this id and does not create any issue. Even my sample ios app (in Native - Swift) same id login successfully. Might be some issue with flutter itself

Comment: Thanks for your support through the debugging. SDK is working fine, The only issue is with Older SDK which does not support passcode feature of google.